# ShowopenDialog not working under actionlistener

Tags: java, actionlistener

So I have been trying to make a filechooser that opens a text file and then paste the contents in a JtextArea I have defined as textArea.
But I cannot get my showOpenDialog to not give an error while having the argument (this), and I researched and the answer was to fill in (null) and this does make the filechooser work but when I try to print the contents of it it also just returns null. I am using the Eclipse program hence the auto filled code.
I am fairly new to Java and have no clue what is going wrong.
Im really sorry if this is not the way to post things here.

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Bladeren");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(
    new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
            int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                System.out.println("Selected file: " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                String content = readFile(selectedFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                System.out.println(content);
                textArea.setText(content);
            }

        }

        private String readFile(File selectedFile, Charset utf8) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showOpenDialog(java.awt.Component)) that the parameter has to be from type `Component`. So what does **`this`** mean in your example? Which other class/interface does your class `extends` from or `implements`?

You didn't paste the code of your `readFile` method but ask why it returns null? This way we cannot help you so please post the code.

Comment: I was very stupid and did not look too much in my readfile method, thank you for pointing this out and this has led me in the right direction and it is fixed now thank you very much!